# Calling a SQL Server stored procedure from postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

Is there any way to call a remote stored procedure on SQL Server from postgres ?

I need to call a stored procedure that receive 3 parameters and make an insert on a remote SQL Server database, if this is possible how can I know if the query was OK or if it was an error during the insert, because both tables on databases need to have the same info.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html

Comment: Dblink only connects to other postgres databases. Dbi-link on the other hand might do the trick.